# How do I install g77 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, ubuntu-20.04, g77

I've been looking for a way to install g77 in ubuntu 20.04 but it seems it is not supported anymore and I can't find anywhere a way to do this. I need it to run some codes that required specifically g77. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You down load the source code and build it yourself.  Or, you install gfortran and see if the code works.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need specifically `g77`. Just install `gfortran`. It compiles the 77 standard too.

You can also add the flag [`-std=legacy`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html), to avoid warnings about legacy code.

There is even the `f77` executable included when installing `gfortran` but it is merely a symbolic link to `gfortran`. So do

```
sudo apt install gfortran
gfortran -std=legacy this_old_code.f
```